# Move each value one step forward in each column in a dataframe

Tags: r

The original dataframe is below:

```
my.dataset1<- data.frame(site=c(11,12,13,14),
                         season=c(21,22,23,24),
                         PH=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Then what i want is below: as you can see, each value move one step formard:

```
my.dataset2<- data.frame(site=c(12,13,14,11),
                         season=c(22,23,24,21),
                         PH=c(2,3,4,1))
```

I try to solve it by the commands below:

```
w<-colnames(dataframe)
for (i in w) {
          nrow(dataframe)
          m<-seq(1,nrow(dataframe))
          m[1:nrow(dataframe)-1]<-dataframe$i[2:nrow(dataframe)]
          m[nrow(dataframe)]<-dataframe$i[1]
          dataframe$i<-m
   }
```

but it doesnot work.
Then I try to fix it by trying the commands below:

```
w<-colnames(dataframe)
for (i in w) {
   print(dataframe$i)
   }
```

what I got is below:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: Rephrasing your question: *How to move first row to the end of a dataframe?*, is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I have make the problem sound complex. But it surely mean just move first row to the end of a dataframe. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

"Moving observations forward" is also known as "lagging" or "shifting". You can accomplish this with the rather flexible `shift` function from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

my.dataset1<- data.frame(site=c(11,12,13,14),
                         season=c(21,22,23,24),
                         PH=c(1,2,3,4))

setDF(lapply(my.dataset1, function(x) shift(x, type = 'lead', fill = x[1L])))[]
#   site season PH
# 1   12     22  2
# 2   13     23  3
# 3   14     24  4
# 4   11     21  1
```

More direct for your use case will be to simply split and recombine your data like:

```
rbind(my.dataset1[-1L, ], my.dataset1[1L, ])
#   site season PH
# 1   12     22  2
# 2   13     23  3
# 3   14     24  4
# 4   11     21  1
```

The advantage of the `shift` approach is its flexibility for a wider variety of use cases.

If you're trying to *overwrite* the original table, the more canonical usage of `data.table` would be to use `:=` like so:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.dataset1)

my.dataset1[ , (names(mydataset1)) := 
              lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, type = 'lead', fill = x[1L]))]
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it.